# I'm trying to make a image transparent using GD library from PHP but running following code, only a portion will be transparent

Tags: php, image, gd, transparent

I'm trying to make a image transparent using GD library from PHP but running following code, only a portion will be transparent.

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng("$second");  
imagealphablending($image, false);
$col_transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $col_transparent);  // set the transparent colour as the background.
imagecolortransparent ($image, $col_transparent); // actually make it transparent
imagesavealpha($image, TRUE);
header( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
imagepng($image);
```

Here you have original image: https://postimg.org/image/y68nw57z1/
Here it's the resulting image: https://postimg.org/image/o4n3t6ic7/

As you can see, exists parts from the resulting image that remain white.
How i can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are flood-fill replacing the white pixels of your image but that won't work on pixels that are completely enclosed by non-white pixels (as in any paint program). Instead you can modify the definition of the colour white to make it transparent:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($second);
imagetruecolortopalette($image, false, 255);
$index = imagecolorclosest($image, 255, 255, 255); // find index of white.
imagecolorset($image, $index, 0, 0, 0, 127); // replace white with transparent black.
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

Comment: Exists modalities to increase quality of image?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'increase quality'. All available GD functions are [listed in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php). If you have a specific problem please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: As you can see here(it's a merge of 2 images, one it's from above and another it's with colors): https://postimg.org/image/p94fuduqj/   , the image losing from quality and have white shapes around letters.

Comment: That's a side-effect of doing a straight colour replacement. You will need much more advanced techniques to remove the white background and preserve anti-aliasing around letters. Is this really something you need to do programmatically? Using software like Photoshop would make this easy.

Comment: I know with photoshop it's easy but i recieve images without transparency and it' a lot of work to make 1000 images transparent from photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works great.  Here is some code to prove it.  I am using the Google API to create a qr code with a white background.  Then using your code to change the white to transparent, I display the qr code with a red background.

```
<?php
// Use Google api to create qr code with white background
//$qrContentText = 'This is a Test';
$qrContentText = 'https://google.com';
$encodedQrContentText = urlencode($qrContentText);
$src = 'https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=540x540&chld=H&choe=UTF-8&chl='.$encodedQrContentText;
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 0;
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $src);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
// Getting binary data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$sourceQRImage = imagecreatefromstring($response);
// Make white background transparent instead
imagetruecolortopalette($sourceQRImage, false, 255);
$index = imagecolorclosest($sourceQRImage, 255, 255, 255); // find index of white.
imagecolorset($sourceQRImage, $index, 0, 0, 0, 127); // replace white with transparent black.
// Get height & width of image
$sourceQRWidth = intval( imagesx( $sourceQRImage ) );
$sourceQRHeight = intval( imagesy( $sourceQRImage ) );
// Display image in the browser
ob_start();
imagepng($sourceQRImage);
$ImageData=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo '<div style="background-color: red; width: ' . $sourceQRWidth . 'px; height: ' . $sourceQRHeight . 'px"><img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($ImageData).'"></div>';
imagedestroy($sourceQRImage);
?>
```